# How was the sense of "brazen insolence" of "cheek" derived?

Tags: meaning, etymology

etymonline says

> cheek (n.)
>
> "either of the two fleshy sides of the face below the eyes," Old
> English ceace, cece "jaw, jawbone," in late Old English also "the
> fleshy wall of the mouth," of uncertain origin, from Proto-Germanic
> *kaukon (source also of Middle Low German kake "jaw, jawbone," Middle Dutch kake "jaw," Dutch kaak), not found outside West Germanic,
> probably a substrate word.
>
> Words for "cheek," "jaw," and "chin" tend to run together in IE
> languages (compare PIE *genw-, source of Greek genus "jaw, cheek,"
> geneion "chin," and English chin); Aristotle considered the chin as
> the front of the "jaws" and the cheeks as the back of them. The other
> Old English word for "cheek" was ceafl (see jowl (n.1)).
>
> > A thousand men he [Samson] slow eek with his hond, And had no wepen
> > but an asses cheek. [Chaucer, "Monk's Tale"]
>
> In reference to the buttocks from c. 1600. The sense of "brazen
> insolence" is from 1840, perhaps from a notion akin to **that** which led
> to jaw "insolent speech," mouth off, etc. To turn the other cheek is
> an allusion to Matthew v.39 and Luke vi.29. Cheek-by-jowl "with cheeks
> close together," hence "in intimate contact" is from 1570s; earlier in
> same sense was cheek-by-cheek (early 14c.). In ballroom dancing,
> cheek-to-cheek is from 1919 (earlier it was a measurement of apples).

How was the sense of "brazen insolence" derived? Is it related to the sense of the facial part? What is "that"?

Does cheek in "tongue in cheek" mean the facial part or "brazen insolence"? Also I don't understand etymonline:

> tongue-in-cheek (adv.)
>
> 1856, from phrase to speak with one's tongue in one's cheek "to speak
> insincerely" (1748), suggestive of sly irony or humorous insincerity,
> perhaps a stage trick to convey irony to the audience.

Comment: The Old English word cheek, meaning both cheek and jaw, came to mean ‘rude or disrespectful behaviour’ in the mid 19th century. The sense probably comes from the idea of a person's cheeks moving as he rudely answers a superior back.

Comment: What is " superior back"?

Comment: Answers a superior [person] back. To answer back is to reply.

Comment: tongue-in-cheek is an idiom. Are Indo-European languages really important to this question? An idea similar to *that which* came about with the Norman invasion of Britian.

Comment: You may be onto something with cheek meaning ass. But you misunderstood Samson's jawbone of an ass - meaning donkey: "Asses cheek ... In reference to the buttocks."

Comment: "A notion akin (similar) to **the one** which led to _jaw_ meaning _insolent speech_." (I've heard of _jaw_ meaning _talk_, but not _insolent  speech_.)

Comment: @KateBunting See the verb entries at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaw. Personally, I think more of "Enough of your *lip*!"

Answer (score 2):

> How was the sense of "brazen insolence" derived? Is it related to the sense of the facial part?

Only indirectly. The dictionary doesn't say *for sure*, but *maybe* it was similar to other uses that use facial parts to talk about rude or impudent speech, like "jaw" or "mouth off."

> What is "that"? [in "... perhaps from a notion akin to that which led to *jaw*..."]

You could replace "that" with "the one." You could paraphrase the quote above as

> ... perhaps from a notion related to the notion which led to...

Just in case there's any confusion, there's no etymological connection between "brazen" and "cheek."